# Лаг при открытии фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Как избавиться от лага (задержка 1-1.5 секунды), при открытии пункта в меню? Лаг записал на видео: http://vimple.co/ee0af4390aa544ccbd0b842b847895ef

Я создал новый проект на основе Navigation Drawer Activity, но это не особо на общую картину влияет, так эта проблема есть и при использовании Bottom Navigation Activity и просто при запуске фрагмента таким образом:

```
ShareFragment frg4 = new ShareFragment ();
FragmentTransaction trans4 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

trans4.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
trans4.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, frg4);
trans4.addToBackStack(null);
trans4.commit();
```

Сам фрагмент ничего кроме разметки в xml и стандартного кода не имеет:

```
public class ShareFragment extends Fragment {

private ShareViewModel shareViewModel;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    shareViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ShareViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share, container, false);


    return root;
}}
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать customanimation() и addtobackstack()

Comment: Увы, но это не помогает)